# Github Bash hanging on Pushing to git+ssh:

Tags: git, github, ssh, git-bash

I have seen about a dozen other threads on here about *errors* when trying to push to a repo, but I get 0 errors and 0 feedback.

`$ GIT_TRACE=1 git push
 trace: built-in: git 'push'
 trace: run_command: 'ssh' 'git@github.com' 'git-receive-pack '\''/REPO/URL/SNIP'\'''`

which gets stuck and does not give me any feedback, up to thirty minutes later.

`ssh -v git@github.com` returns nothing the same way.

`git pull | push -v` same thing does nothing no errors no feedback.

If I use the GUI-->Push I get `Pushing to git+ssh://git@github.com/REPOURL.git` and a grim "`Working... please wait...`"

This was all working a week or two ago, I've used SSH to push for quite some time and it is always very fast and has never done something like this. Any ideas anyone? Thanks

EDIT: I knew I managed to forget something... I'm using Windows 10 + Gitbash.

Comment: are you using git-bash on windows, or real git and bash?

Comment: @ᴳᵁᴵᴰᴼ my bad, post edited to reflect that I'm using git-bash on windows10